# XMLSec: What's wrong with the signature? ("Reference for URI has no XMLSignatureInput")

Tags: apache, digital-signature, digital-certificate, xml-signature, xmlsec

I'm using apache-santuario 1.4.4 to generate this signed message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-SEC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#DS-OM">
          <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
          </ds:Transforms>
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
          <ds:DigestValue>8nZkH.....99alYEU4=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>
        XSwt/8HzsnWewj.....8dHwY+FVCkhlg==
      </ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>
            MIID4TCCAsmgAwIB....WQuq/eiErGfyU9ZNmKFpA==
          </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
        <ds:KeyValue>
          <ds:RSAKeyValue>
            <ds:Modulus>
              zSmjLBHhvxfE03pEUaq8x.....D4b63mMF8p+3XAYmgw==
            </ds:Modulus>
            <ds:Exponent>AQBA</ds:Exponent>
          </ds:RSAKeyValue>
        </ds:KeyValue>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body SOAP-SEC:Id="DS-OM">
    <ns1:Servic xmlns:ns1="http://www.foo.es/Schemas">
      ...
    </ns1:Servic>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I send it to the service that I'm working with, it replies this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://www.foo.com/Schemas">ns1:DigitalSignatureError</faultcode>
      <faultstring>The Reference for URI #DS-OM has no XMLSignatureInput</faultstring>
      <detail>
         <string/>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've googled a lot but haven't found almost anything about this error. 
Is the reference bad declared? what could be wrong? Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"DS-OM" is defined as "SOAP-SEC:Id" - I think this is what's causing the problem here, it could be that SOAP-SEC:Id is not a proper xml:id or does not correctly get recognized as one. What you could do to circumvent this is to declare your `Reference` using an XPath transform instead:

```
<ds:Reference URI="">
      <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
           <ds:XPath xmlns:soapenv="&soapenv;" xmlns:SOAP-SEC="&SOAP-SEC;">
             //soapenv:Envelope[@SOAP-SEC:Id='DS-OM']
           <ds:XPath>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      </ds:Transforms>
      ....
</ds:Reference>
```